# Facebook Linter - Page Admin URI

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, admin

Facebook's Linter used to give me the admin uri when I was logged in with an admin account. Also, it would show what the like button would look like on the page which would have another link to the admin page. Were these features taken away with the new Facebook changes?

How can I find the amin uri of website pages that are liked without the lint feature?

Answer (score 0):

What is the og:type of page? This is true only for real-life types, page with og:type article does not have its own "voice".